# JaxRs JSON provider for Scala

Tags: json, scala, jax-rs

Is there an out of the box Jax-RS JSON provider that works with Scala types outside the box?

Right now I am using Jackson, but it has trouble with serializing an `Option[Environment]` where `case class Environment(value: String) extends AnyVAl`

I suspect not given the compile-time nature of Scala vs the runtime nature of Jax-RS but I thought to ask before reinventing the wheel.